Effect of heating on buoyant force
In my book there was a question wherein a sphere was submerged inside water at 10 deg Celsius, and then it was heated to a higher temperature. The question asked whether the buoyant force increases or decreases, and the answer key said it will decrease
However, some sources online claim the contrary, namely, buoyant force generally increases as temperature increases
A friend of mine presented the following explanation:
Since force of buoyancy
$F = V\rho g$
now $V$ will increase with temperature, but density of water ($\rho$) will decrease, so the question in the textbook could be implying that the water along with the sphere were heated (or maybe just the water), whereas the sources online only heated the object not the fluid

It’s not clear what exactly is being heated

Yh, and that's where the problem arises.
